# Clearing a specific arraylist instead of all the copies of it

Tags: java, arraylist

When I clear one of my arraylist, it clears all the copies of that arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> testa = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>();
testa.add("Dog");
testb = testa;
testa.clear();
```

Now testb also gets cleared. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: because u didnt copy the arraylist but just reference it to testa.

Comment: http://c4learn.com/javaprogramming/assigning-object-reference-variables-class-concept-in-java-programming/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `testb`  is refferring to `testa`.That's when a changes b also changes.

When you do `testb = testa;`  it's like ,

```
+-----+
| testa |--------\
+-----+         \    +----------------+
                 --->| (same list)    |
+-----+         /    |  testa         |
| testb |--------/   +----------------+
+-----+
```

If you don't want that, create a **new** independent `ArrayList`.

Passing the actual list to new [`constructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29),

```
ArrayList<String> testa = new ArrayList<String>();
testa.add("Dog");
ArrayList<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>(testa);
testa.clear();
```

or with [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method

```
  ArrayList<String> testa = new ArrayList<String>();
  testa.add("Dog");
  ArrayList<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>();
  testb.addAll(testa);
  testa.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<String> testa = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>();
    testa.add("Dog");
    List<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>(testa);
    testa.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
ArrayList<String> testa = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> testb = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`testa` and `testb` are their own, separate, unique instances, which point to two different `ArrayList` references.  If you change one, you don't affect the other.

At *this* point:

```
testb = testa;
```

You have now set `testb` to point to the same reference as `testa`.  Anything done with `testb` will affect `testa`, and vice versa.

If you want to copy the elements from `testa` to `testb`, new an instance of an `ArrayList` with `testb` as your argument:

```
testb = new ArrayList<>(testa);
```